# How to hide the preview window in windows explorer?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am making a batch file to password protect a hidden folder.
How can I make it so the user cant view the preview window at the side, since the preview window allows them to see the password that is set in the .bat file.

Comment: What if they open the file in notepad?

Comment: well is there a way to protect the file from being edited too?

Comment: Can't they see the content without modifying?

Comment: Yes the content is viewable, so would be ideal to keep the file only runnable and also hidden in preview

Comment: Use batch-file string manipulation to get the password out of an obfuscated long string that appears random to a user.

Comment: @wOxxOm the problem with that is users with even a basic knowledge of batch could `echo` this long obscure string and extract the password.

Answer (score 2):

To make the code of your batch file both hidden and un-editable, the best option is to convert it to an exe. I would recommend you use [this bat-to-exe converter](http://www.f2ko.de).

Also FYI, making a folder hidden is a rather ineffective protection step that only works against layman tech users. Perhaps encrypting the folder may be a better solution for you.